# Manually authenticate use spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security and it works fine, but now I want to start the security process manually, do to client changes I need to get in **my** controller the user name and password (the form wont call "j_spring_security_check" directly)

I thought of 2 options with both I have some problems:

1. After I get the parameters and do something I will send a post request to j_spring_security_check url. My code:

   public void test(loginDTO loginDTO) {

   ```
   MultiValueMap<String, String> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
   HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

   body.add(
        "j_username",
        loginDTO.getJ_username());

   body.add(
        "j_password",
        loginDTO.getJ_password());

   HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(
                             body, headers);
   headers.add(
           "Accept",
           MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
   restTemplate.exchange(
                 "http://localhost:8080/XXX/j_spring_security_check",
                 HttpMethod.POST,
                 httpEntity,
                 HttpServletResponse.class);
   }
   ```

This doesn't work and I get :500 internal server error why?

1. second option- I did the following:

   ```
   public void test2(loginDTO loginDTO, HttpServletRequest request) {

     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token =
                   new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                             loginDTO.getJ_username(),
                             loginDTO.getJ_password());

     token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(request));
     Authentication authentication = this.authenticate(token);

     SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

     this.sessionRegistry.registerNewSession(
                       request.getSession().getId(),
                       authentication.getPrincipal());
   }
   ```

   The problem is that onAuthenticationSuccess is not called. and it feels wrong, that I'm missing the point of using spring security.

What is the correct why?

Comment: In most cases where your believe you need to do what you're asking, you're actually looking at the problem from a wrong angle (hence the difficulties you're facing). Can you be more precise about what exactly are you trying to solve and I will probably be able to suggest a different approach?

Comment: The problem is that the login form is not under my control and the way it needs to work is that my controller gets a login dto with the user name and password and I need to authenticate it using spring security.

Answer (score 2):

I typically do the following:

```
@Controller
public class AuthenticationController
{
  @Autowired
  AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  @Autowired
  SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

  @RequestMapping(method = Array(RequestMethod.POST), value = Array("/authenticate"))
  public String authenticate(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  {
    Authentication result = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext.setAuthentication(result);

    this.securityContextRepository.saveContext(SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), request, response);

    return "successView";
  }
}
```

The reasons for using this approach is:

1. Very simple, just a few lines of code if you ignore exception handling and such.
2. Leverages existing Spring Security components.
3. Uses Spring Security components configured in the application configuration and allows them to be changed as and when required.  For example, the authentication may be done against an RDBMS, LDAP, web service, Active Directory, etc. without the custom code needing to worry about it.

Comment: This is very similar to my second option. but then the onAuthenticationSuccess is not called.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use as most as possible from the normal Authentication Process, then you could create a mocked `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` (`org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest` and `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse`) containing login and password, and then invoke

```
 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)`
```

afterwards you will also need to invoke `SessionAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(..)` and `successfulAuthentication(..)`

This is all a bit tricky, because of private fileds, so this is my solution:

```
public class ExtendedUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
                           extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {


    @Override
    public void manualAuthentication(String login,
                                     String password,
                                     HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
                              throws IOException, ServletException {

        /** I do not mock the request, I use the existing request and
            manipulate them*/
        AddableHttpRequest addableHttpRequest =
                                  new AddableHttpRequest(httpServletRequest);
        addableHttpRequest.addParameter("j_username", login);
        addableHttpRequest.addParameter("j_password", password);

        MockHttpServletResponse mockServletResponse =
                                  new MockHttpServletResponse();
        Authentication authentication = this.attemptAuthentication(
                                                addableHttpRequest,
                                                mockServletResponse);

        this.reflectSessionStrategy().onAuthentication(
                                        authentication,
                                        addableHttpRequest,
                                        mockServletResponse);
        this.successfulAuthentication(addableHttpRequest,
                                      mockServletResponse,
                                      authentication);
    }

    private SessionAuthenticationStrategy reflectSessionStrategy() {

        Field sessionStrategyField =
                      ReflectionUtils.findField(
                             AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.class,
                             "sessionStrategy",
                             SessionAuthenticationStrategy.class);
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(sessionStrategyField);

        return (SessionAuthenticationStrategy)
               ReflectionUtils.getField(sessionStrategyField, this);
    }
}
```

`AddableHttpRequest` is like a mock that is based on an real request

```
public class AddableHttpRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    /** The params. */
    private HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();


    public AddableHttpRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
        return "POST";
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(final String name) {
        // if we added one, return that one
        if (params.get(name) != null) {
            return params.get(name);
        }
        // otherwise return what's in the original request
        return super.getParameter(name);
    }

    public void addParameter(String name, String value) {
        params.put(name, value);
    }    
}
```

An other way, would be implementing your own, authentication filter. Thats a class that invoke the `AuthenticationManager.authenticate(Authentication authentication)`. But this class is also responsible for invoking all the stuff around authentication (what `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter` does)`

Comment: I'm trying to do the filter.doFilter. The method requires FilteChain how do I get it?

Answer (score 0):

OK so I combined @Ralph and @manish answers and this is what I did:

(twoFactorAuthenticationFilter is an extension of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter)

```
 public void manualAuthentication(loginDTO loginDTO, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
        ServletException {

    AddableHttpRequest addableHttpRequest = new AddableHttpRequest(
                                       request);

    addableHttpRequest.addParameter(
                    "j_username",
                    loginDTO.getJ_username());
    addableHttpRequest.addParameter(
                    "j_password",
                    loginDTO.getJ_password());

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) twoFactorAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(
                                                                          addableHttpRequest,
                                                                          response);
    if (token.isAuthenticated()) {
        twoFactorAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(
                                   addableHttpRequest,
                                   response,
                                   null,
                                   token);
    }


    }
```

It works fine