# Programmatically Login a user SPring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating a Spring MVC web application using spring security for authentication.

My application has a requirement that the user is logged in automatically when the user accesses a particular URL, say http://www.example.com/login?username=xyz

The user xyz is in the database, and I need to create a session for this user automatically.

Request you to let me know how this can be achieved.

Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: lots of answers on SO and google man...

Comment: the same question came up yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398301/manually-authenticate-use-spring-secrity

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, the idea would be to retrieve the user from the database, make the checks you want and then use the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` to create a new Principal into the current session.

The use of the returned Principal of the method is for subsequent uses on the same request, as the Principal won't be available to be retrieved by normal means until the next request.

```
public Principal doAutoLogin(String username, String password, HttpServletRequest hreq, HttpServletResponse hres, boolean rememberMe) {
        User user = getUserFromDatabase(username);
        if(user != null && passwordsMatch(password, user.getPassword())) {
            try {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
                token.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetails(hreq));
                if(LOG.isDebugEnabled())
                    LOG.debug("Logging in with "+ token.getPrincipal());
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);

                if(rememberMe) {
                    rememberMeServices.onLoginSuccess(hreq, hres, token);
                }
                return token;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
                LOG.error("Failure in autoLogin", e);
                return null;
            }
        }
        else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified credentials can't be found");
        }
    }
```